# Flutter stripe package direct apple pay popup not showing

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am used flutter_stripe package here is the there have some building method for direct showing apple pay popup.
here is some method that are show in flutter stripe documentations.
`Future<bool> isApplePaySupported(); Future<void> presentApplePay(); Future<void> confirmApplePayPayment();`
but this method not working properly

Apple pay popup show directly